# Android PlacePicker setLatLngBounds() does not work

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api

Since I updated my Google Play Services to 9.0.83, when I try to center PlacePicker to a position with setLatLngBounds() method it centers my map at 0,0 in the Atlantic Ocean, independently from which LatLngBounds I insert. Does anybody else have this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Google Service Place picker setLatLngBounds() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296991/android-google-service-place-picker-setlatlngbounds-not-working)

Comment: Do check out the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37318013/4625829) in the above duplicate. Cheers! :)