# Place Picker setLatLngBounds to set the initial latitude and longitude bounds not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

If I am passing in a LatLngBounds to set the initial latitude and longitude bounds to Call setLatLngBounds() on the builder, then pin on the map is always pointed at the center. Also zoom level is not working.

Here is my code:

```
LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
                new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW);
Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(Activity.this);
startActivityForResult (intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Google Service Place picker setLatLngBounds() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296991/android-google-service-place-picker-setlatlngbounds-not-working)