# Google Place API For Android Map Point to Wrong Location (0,0) After Select an Address From Autocomplete

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

**It works fine previously**. I mean the code has not been changed since several months ago. This is what happen now, after I click an address from the autocomplete.

[image]

This is how I call the auto complete and the maps after pick a location.

```
private void openPlaceAutoComplete(){
    try {
        long touchTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(touchTime - latestTouchedTime > BOUNCE_DELAY){
            latestTouchedTime = touchTime;
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_OVERLAY)
                    .build(this.getActivity());
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST);
        }
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then, on ActivityResult

```
else if(requestCode == PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this.getFragmentBaseContext(), data);

            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            builder.setLatLngBounds(LocationHelper.getBoundsFromCenter(place.getLatLng(), PLACE_BOUND_RADIUS));
            try{
                startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            }catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have make sure the place is not null, and it has LatLng object which is not 0,0 and GetBoundsFromCenter function is simply like this.

```
public static LatLngBounds getBoundsFromCenter(LatLng center, double radius){
    LatLng southwest = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, radius * Math.sqrt(2.0), 225);
    LatLng northeast = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, radius * Math.sqrt(2.0), 45);
    return new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
}
```

Comment: sometimes I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in the current release of the Place Picker. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37318013/2994 for more info.

Comment: I am using 8.0.4 and have tried using several play-services version also, including 9.02. Currently the apps require to show current selected address from autocomplete and load nearby locations. Do you have any idea without using setLatLngBounds?