# Android - Google Place Picker does not display search box

Tags: android, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I am trying to make an app which can enable user to "check-in" at a certain location through Google Place Picker.

I use the code from Google :

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(DEFAULT_LOCATION);
Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(LocationActivity.this);
startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

The problem is, the search box doesn't appear in some devices but appears in a certain device.

Here's a snapshot taken from Note 5, in which the search menu appears :

[image: Search Menu appears]

And here's a snapshot taken from Xiaomi Redmii 2 in which it doesn't appear :

[image: Search Menu gone]

It also doesn't appear in, Zenfone C, and S5, Sony Ultra C5..

I've followed Google's tutorial from top to bottom but still hasn't found any solution to this as it happen all of a sudden.

Have anybody been in this predicament before? If yes, any solution??

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue with the latest version of Google Play Services. Any devices that have updated to version 9.0.83 are affected.

See my post regarding this issue: [Android PlacePicker no longer has Search icon after updating to Google Play Services 9.0.83](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266209/android-placepicker-no-longer-has-search-icon-after-updating-to-google-play-serv)

See these bug reports from the Google Maps API bug and feature website:
[Bug: Search Icon not visible in the latest play service update (Version:9.0.83)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9778&q=PlacePicker&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) ----- 
[Bug: Place Picker not showing search icon.](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9793&q=PlacePicker&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) -----
[PlacePicker search icon is gone after updating to Google Play Services 9.0.83](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9777&q=PlacePicker&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars)